# Is there a formal specification (like the Java Language Specification (JLS)) for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, standards, specifications

Is there a definitive specification for Ruby, akin to the Java Language Specification for Java. Googling ruby language specification provides http://ruby-std.netlab.jp/ as a result, but the site is down and i am not sure whether it is current

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Ruby 1.8 has been the subject of several industry standards. The language specifications for Ruby were developed by the Open Standards Promotion Center of the Information-Technology Promotion Agency (a [Japanese government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_of_Japan) agency) for submission to the [Japanese Industrial Standards Committee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_Industrial_Standards_Committee) (JISC) and then to the [International Organization for Standardization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Organization_for_Standardization) (ISO). It was accepted as a Japanese Industrial Standard (JIS X 3017) in 2011<sup>[[24]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29#cite_note-24)</sup> and an international standard ([ISO/IEC 30170](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ISO/IEC_30170)) in 2012.<sup>[[25]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29#cite_note-25)</sup>

#### References

- [Wikipedia/Ruby (programming language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29)

#### See also

- [ruby-std.netlab.jp](http://ruby-std.netlab.jp/) - draft Ruby ISO standard

  - [ruby-standard.org](http://wiki.ruby-standard.org/) - a wiki-format mirror of the draft Ruby ISO standard
- [spec.ruby-doc.org](http://spec.ruby-doc.org/) - a community-driven project to write a complete, executable specification

Comment: Thanks, i notice that spec.ruby-doc.org is an executable spec based on rspec. There does not seem to be any project ongoing for a written spec, so it does seem low on the priority list for the ruby community. Is there no value in having a written spec

Comment: @HN: I don't know Ruby culture enough to comment. That said, I love reading JLS.

Comment: @HN: You could run the specs just for the output, say "Array#length returns blah, Array#length raises an error if blah, ...", to get a textual standard that would be really dull. There is a Ruby ISO standard effort, and a mirror is at http://ruby-standard.org/ Note that work on the builtin library has not started...

Comment: There is now an official spec. Alas, it costs roughly US$250 to read. http://dallarosa.tumblr.com/post/20338743300/ruby-is-accepted-as-an-international-standard http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=59579

Comment: ruby-std.netlab.jp  asks for a username and password. ruby-standard.org makes my Chrome hand me an exception. I'd edit if I knew what to do about it, or downvote if I could.

Answer (score 16):

There is [a draft](http://WWW.IPA.Go.Jp/osc/english/ruby/ruby_draft_specification_agreement.html) for a [formal specification](http://WWW.IPA.Go.Jp/osc/english/ruby/) of Ruby. It is being developed by the [Open Standards Promotion Center](http://WWW.IPA.Go.Jp/osc/english/) of the [Information-Technology Promotion Agency](http://WWW.IPA.Go.Jp/index-e.html) (a Japanese government agency) for submission to the [Japanese Industrial Standards Committee](http://WWW.JISC.Go.Jp/eng/) and then further on to the [International Organization for Standardization](http://ISO.Org/).

However, nobody actually uses this specification. **The specification that is *actually* being used is the *directly executable* [RubySpec](https://github.com/ruby/spec)**, which is used by all the major Ruby implementors like [Rubinius](http://Rubini.us/), [IronRuby](http://IronRuby.Net/), [JRuby](http://JRuby.Org/), [MacRuby](http://MacRuby.Org/), [MagLev](http://MagLev.GemStone.Com/) and so on.

The three main differences between the ISO Draft Specification and RubySpec are:

1. RubySpec is *complete*: it covers the entire Ruby language, and the entire core library, from version 1.8.7 to 1.9.2 and 1.9.3. The ISO Draft Specification only covers a very small subset of the intersection of 1.8 and 1.9.
2. RubySpec is written in *Ruby* (which is a language that every Rubyist can read), the ISO Draft Specification is written in English, or rather in ISO Standardese (which is a language that only a handful of people on the planet can fully understand).
3. RubySpec is *executable*: you can just run it against your Ruby implementation to see what you are still missing.

Another great source (pun intended) of information about the behavior of Ruby is the [source code of the Rubinius kernel](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/tree/master/kernel/), which implements the semantics of the Ruby language and the Ruby core library. (Note: a lot of people prefer [the source code](https://GitHub.Com/Ruby/Ruby/) of [YARV](http://AtDot.Net/yarv/), but I don't, for two reasons: firstly, YARV is in C, which is a language that not every Rubyist knows, whereas Rubinius is in Ruby, which (hopefully) every Rubiyst knows, and secondly, the Rubinius codebase is much better structured, well-designed, well-organized, well-tested, well-documented.)

Comment: Great answer. Ah, I wish RubySpec *was* complete... It *aims* to be, but a simple search for `it "needs to be reviewed for completeness"` will convince you it isn't. It's not even clear to me it *could* be complete.

Comment: Basing your understanding of a platform on a specific implementation of that platform is a *really* bad idea. You end up writing implementation-dependent code. Of course, I make my living writing technical documentation, so I'm biased.

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch: Unfortunately, for more than 13 years, there was only one implementation. So, that implementation *became* the specification. Yes, there is an ISO spec now, but that only covers a small subset of the language, a *tiny* subset of the core library and *none* of the standard library.

Comment: @JörgWMittag But now there are multiple implementations. And none of them are static, changing with upgrades and bug fixes. If you base your understanding of a feature on the way it works on a particular implementation, your understanding may be wrong for other implementations or even later versions of the same implementation.

Comment: Notice that RubySpec is now dead. Its maintainer cited a lack of usage from MRI developers as his reason: http://rubinius.com/2014/12/31/matz-s-ruby-developers-don-t-use-rubyspec/

Comment: @xji RubySpec seems to be actively maintained on GitHub, with the last update a few days ago (mid-February 2023): https://github.com/ruby/spec

Answer (score 0):

If you go to

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax_rdoc.html

or

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/

"The official Ruby API documentation"

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/

then under 'pages' choose 'syntax'

Then you get this page, with its links to other relevant pages

**https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax_rdoc.html**

**The Ruby syntax is large and is split up into the following sections:**

**Literals**
Numbers, Strings, Arrays, Hashes, etc.

**Assignment**
Assignment and variables

**Control Expressions**
if, unless, while, until, for, break, next, redo

**Methods**
Method and method argument syntax

**Calling Methods**
How to call a method (or send a message to a method)

**Modules and Classes**
Creating modules and classes including inheritance

**Exceptions**
Exception handling syntax

**Precedence**
Precedence of ruby operators

**Refinements**
Use and behavior of the experimental refinements feature

**Miscellaneous**
alias, undef, BEGIN, END